# How can I test values for equality by using an array instead of chaining a gazillion ORs?

Tags: ruby

How can I shift all of these OR statements into something that is done via an array or iterator?

Here's the long inelegant OR chain:

```
type = "Open top" if cargo_operation_container_shifting[12] == 1 or cargo_operation_conatiner_shifting[16] ==1 or cargo_operations_container_shifting[99] == 1
```

(this is a short example)

Here is the progress I have made on making this into an array so far:

```
open_top_array  = [12, 16, 99]
type = "Open top" if open_top_array.each { |n| cargo_operation_container_shifting[n] == 1 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You the [`any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) method:

```
open_top_array  = [12, 16, 99]
type = "Open top" if open_top_array.any?{ |n| cargo_operation_container_shifting[n] == 1 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
type = 'Open top' if [12, 16, 99].any? do |n| 
  cargo_operation_container_shifting[n] == 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `values_at`:

```
type = "Open top" if cargo_operation_container_shifting.values_at(12,16,99).any?{|v| v == 1}
```